# PAM service (sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3

Tags: ssh

On my Ubuntu server when I login using ssh it displays this message.

```
vps48446 PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
```

How do I stop it so that I can work without any disturbance of these auto populated messages?

Comment: where does it populate this message?

Comment: It populates these message in console when i login using ssh

Answer (score 1):

It’s caused by `pam_unix` disagreeing with `sshd` on how many times a user can retry their password before getting disconnected.

To stop it, add

```
MaxAuthTries 3
```

to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

This solution borrowed from https://juju.nz/michaelh/2014/04/stopping-pam-servicesshd-ignoring-max-retries-errors-in-syslog.
Works for me (Ubuntu 16 LTS Server), but I expect it to work independent of the distribution or release.